# Sublime Text 2 - HTML CSS suggestions

Tags: html, css, sublimetext2, autosuggest

I started using this great editor. Unfortunately I missing here one improvement (from NuSphere PhpED - past editor that I've used, this understanding)

Example:

I have a project open, I open the HTML file, for example, do I wonder with some ID and then in the CSS file, it's easy to find through insinuation. Of course it works the other way around (create something in CSS and HTML then it easily through the whisperings find).

In this sublime does not work. Is there a plugin? thank you
(screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/v39O8.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand the middle paragraph at all.

Comment: Please see screen. When I wrote for example in HTML page 
<div id="test"></div> So after the css via autosuggestion box -> #t  (autocomplete) I find #test 
It works in both directions (HTML -> CSS, CSS -> HTML), it helps to write fast and do not need to remember the names of the elements in the HTML, and  classes and IDs in CSS. It's understandable?

Comment: I don't believe Sublime Text 2 can do that out of the box - there doesn't seem to be much autocompletion that works with more than the current file.

Comment: It is a pity, PhpED knows it. Very simplificated writing code :(

Answer (score 6):

From what I understand, you want to be able to link autocompletes from one file to another? I'm actually pretty interested in this too, just scanned through the [package-control listings](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/community) and found:

[***All Autocomplete***](https://github.com/alienhard/SublimeAllAutocomplete) <------

So **yes** you can do it! Go install the package :)

Comment: Yeah, going to start using it aswell

Answer (score 0):

You can install sublime codeintel package....it might helps.
Here is the link: https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel

Answer (score 0):

Try this [CSS Sublime Package](https://github.com/subhaze/CSS-sublime-package)

hear it works quite well...about to give it a shot